# Pre-handle third party library method in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns

We are exploring Micrometer metrics collection library in Spring Boot 1.5.

Micrometer provides a static method in the `Tag` interface to create tags for metrics.

```
public interface Tag {
    String getKey();

    String getValue();

    static Tag of(String key, String value) {
        return new ImmutableTag(key, value);
    }
}
```

The implementation of ImmutableTag is as follows:

```
public class ImmutableTag implements Tag {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public ImmutableTag(String key, String value) {
        requireNonNull(key);
        requireNonNull(value);
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
...other methods...
}
```

Now, we are collecting some tags programmatically, and might end up with a null tag (which will throw an exception because of `requireNonNull()`). But on encountering a null, we are okay with replacing the tag value with a default string (say "unknown").

What is the best way to handle this?

I have thought of the following:

1. **Try / Catch:** Surround all such statements in a `try/catch` block. I understand this can be expensive and difficult to maintain.
2. **Handle null on our end:** `Check for any null tag being passed`, and replace it with default string. However, we will have a lot of such statements, and want to have some sort of configuration that this happens by default.
3. **Wrapper interface:** Create a `TagWrapper interface`, replace null with default value, and call the `Tag.of()` method. Seems like the best option to me now, however, when this is no longer needed (maybe a method like this is introduced later in the library later), getting rid of the wrapper will include a lot of changes.

Is there some configuration in Spring that allows me to pre-handle third-party library methods without creating a wrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe use Spring AOP.  Something like:

```
@around(value="execution(* package.name.class.Tag.of)")
public void wrapTags(ProceedingJoinPoint call){
   try {
     Object[] args = call.getArgs();
     // wrap args in Optional.ofNullable
     call.proceed();
   } catch (Exception e){
      // handle exception
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the way to go :)

Comment: Won't work with Spring AOP, since I want to intercept a "static" method.
Keeping the answer accepted, since it does solve the problem (for non-static methods)

Comment: @user2684198 - What did you decide to use?

Comment: Ultimately I used #3 above after a discussion with the team.

I am still a little skeptical about it though. It involves an unnecessary wrapper, which may introduce a lot of changes someday. But whatever works for now :) (I am just an intern!)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with add this properties:

in application.yml:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    deserialization:
      fail-on-null-creator-properties: false
```

or application.properties:

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.fail-on-null-creator-properties= false
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but can't you wrap the values in an Optional that are being passed to the `Tag` interface?

```
// wrapping values in Optional
public static String wrapTags(String s){
  return Optional.ofNullable(s).orElse("UNKNOWN");
}
```

Comment: We definitely can. But we will have to add this to a lot of places and looking for something that helps avoid it.

Comment: If you're worried about updating all the spots in your code, then I'd just go with option 3 above.

Comment: Another option is to use Spring AOP and wrap all calls to `Tag` in a pointcut which adds in your defensive code